# Accessing the last child of a child in firebase real time database

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I want to access the last child within a certain child in real time database [image]

(this child)

I tried using this code but it returns `{-MkHrcId8EfYpqFWqNrw: {Sender: 97205********, message: hello}}`  when accessing snapshot.value, but returns null when when trying to access `snapshot.value['message']`

```
  Future<String> getLastMessage() async{
    final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
    String RoomId; // RoomId is the name of the first child, the one that starts with 587 in the image
    String lastMessage;
    lastMessage = await ref.child(RoomId).orderByKey().limitToLast(1).once().then((snapshot) {
      snapshot.value['message'];
    return lastMessage;
    });
```

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance. Can you `print(snapshot.value)` inside the `then()` callback, and edit your question to show the updated code and its output?

Comment: The code actually returns `{-MkHrcId8EfYpqFWqNrw: {Sender: 97205********, message: hello}}` when printing `snapshot.value`, but returns null when when trying to print `snapshot.value['message']`  @Frank van Puffelen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on @Frank van Puffelen answer the solution ended up being this

```
lastMessage = await ref.child(RommId).orderByKey().limitToLast(1).once().then((snapshot) {
       return (snapshot.value.values).toList()[0]['message'];
    });
```

Comment: Writing you own answer based on the information in mine without at least upvoting my answer is rather unusual. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

So your callback will need to handle that list, by looping over its children (in `snapshot.value.values` iirc), or by accessing the first entry directly with `snapshot.value.toList()[0]['message']`.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a method called `values` for `value` (it doesn't show up in the suggestions) but when typing it anyway it returns `({Sender: 97205********, message: hello})` but now I am unable to access `message` since using `['message]` returns an exception 'Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class '_CompactIterable<Object?>' has no instance method '[]'.'

Comment: That means you're still missing the loop I mentioned. You need to get the first item from the list/map, and looping or `[0]` are the two options you have for that.